# My new category attribute is not saving to the EAV table

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a custom attribute for categories, i have got it to display on the backend but when I press save nothing is happening. I have checked the `eav_attribute` table and it is not inserting!

> /Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace XX\XX\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //Category Attribute Create Script
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'category_front_label',
            [
                'group' => 'autosmart_category_fields',
                'label' => 'Category Short Description',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 1,
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => false
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Settings</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="category_front_label">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5000</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Label</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I then run (in this order)

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento cache:clean
```

It is displaying as a field in the back end but not saving, presumably because the install script isn't creating the entry in the `eav_attribute` table. Been stuck on this issue for a few days.

Answer (score 2):

Had a very similar problem. I was missing the `namespace XX\XX\Setup;` at the beginning of `/Setup/InstallData.php`, so make sure to include it in your PHP class file.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove the module from the setup_module before running compile and upgrade otherwise install schema didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my plugin already included an installschema. So instead of InstallData.php I had to setup an UpgradeData.php script in my setup file. This worked.

```
<?php

namespace XXX\XXX\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Catalog Data Upgrade
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Class Constructor
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory     $eavSetupFactory     Eav setup factory.
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade the module data.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup   The setup interface
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context The module Context
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'xx',
                [
                    'type'         => 'int',
                    'label'        => '',
                    'input'        => 'select',
                    'sort_order'   => 100,
                    'source'       => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'global'     => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible'      => true,
                    'required'     => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'default'      => '0',
                    'group'        => 'Display Settings',
                    'position' => 999
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```